# How to turn my code (which has multiple classes) to exe?

Tags: python, exe

I have a code that is working currently. It consists of multiple classes and a main class. It takes data from Excel files and write the conclusion matrix to an another Excel file.

I want the main class to work by only double click and write to Excel without getting into the IDE.

I tried pyInstaller multiple times and it didn't work. Then, I tried 'open with' python. It didn't work either. I am suspecting because of the other classes and Excel files.

When I use these methods it doesn't give any error.

Comment: In general this isn't a common python use case - generally you execute python scripts from the command line. Tools do exist to help with this, though - look into [`py2exe`](http://www.py2exe.org/).

Comment: without a [mcve] it's hard to provide much in the way of assistance for you. when you "use" these methods/classes, it works, because you're running them from python and properly instantiating the classes so that their methods are accessible. you'll need an entry point (and possibly parameters w/ fallbacks and error-handling) to do anything with these as executable.

Comment: I think this will helpful. We tried it. Gives Proper Output:- https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/compiler.htm